# How do I get constants defined by Ruby's Module class via reflection?

Tags: ruby, reflection, metaprogramming

I was trying to get Matz and Flanagan's "Ruby Programming Language" metaprogramming chapter into my head, However I couldn't understand the output from the following code snippet that I dreamed up:

```
p Module.constants.length           # => 88
$snapshot1 = Module.constants       
class A
  NAME=:abc

  $snapshot2 = Module.constants
  p $snapshot2.length               # => 90
  p $snapshot2 - $snapshot1         # => ["A", "NAME"]

end
p Module.constants.length           # => 89
p Module.constants - $snapshot1     # => ["A"]
p A.constants                       # => ["NAME"]
```

The book states that the class method `constants` returns the list of constants for the class (as you can see in the output for `A.constants`).
I was trying to get the list of constants defined for the Module class when I came across the above strange behavior.

`A`'s constants show up in Module.constants. How do I get the list of constants defined by the Module class?

The [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001656) state

> `Module.constants` returns all constants defined in the system. including names of all classes and methods

Since `A` inherits its implementation from `Module.constants`, how does it behave differently in the base and derived types?

```
p A.class               # => Class
p A.class.ancestors       # => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel]
```

*Note: If you're using Ruby 1.9, `constants` would return an array of symbols instead of strings.*

Comment: Did I answer your question? I'm asking because my answer was not 'accepted' but didn't ask for any additional info...

Comment: @Marc - Your answer led me down to more questions and more scribbling and erasing. Spent this week trying to wrap my head around the method resolution scheme... I'm still not clear as to what the possibilities are - however I think I'm 90% sure as to how it works. See my post below.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Good question!

Your confusion is due to the fact that the class method `Module.constants` hides the instance method `Module#constants` for `Module`.

In Ruby 1.9, this has been addressed by adding an optional parameter:

```
# No argument: same class method as in 1.8:
Module.constants         # ==> All constants
# One argument: uses the instance method:
Module.constants(true)   # ==> Constants of Module (and included modules)
Module.constants(false)  # ==> Constants of Module (only).
```

In your example above, `A.constants` calls `Module#constants` (the instance method), while `Module.constants` calls, well, `Module.constants`.

In Ruby 1.9, you thus want to call `Module.constants(true)`.

In Ruby 1.8, it is possible to call the instance method `#constants` on `Module`. You need to get the instance method and bind it as a class method (using a different name):

```
class << Module
  define_method :constants_of_module, Module.instance_method(:constants)
end

# Now use this new class method:
class Module
   COOL = 42
end
Module.constants.include?("COOL")  # ==> false, as you mention
Module.constants_of_module         # ==> ["COOL"], the result you want
```

I wish I was able to backport the 1.9 functionality completely to 1.8 for my `backports` gem, but I can't think of a way to get only the constants of a Module, excluding the inherited ones, in Ruby 1.8.

*Edit*: Just changed the official documentation to correctly reflect this...

Comment: @Marc - would appreciate it if you could go over my understanding of method resolution and confirm it. Blog post link in my post below. Thanks and Accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

I had to go back into my thinking cave for a while after Marc's response. Tinkered with more code snippets and then some more. Finally when Ruby's method resolution seemed to make sense wrote it down as a blog post so that I don't forget.

Notation: If **A"** is the eigenclass of **A**

When `A.constants` is called, method resolution (refer to the image in [my blog post](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2010/03/method-resolution-in-ruby-or-how-to.html) to have a visual aid) looks up the following locations in order

- `MyClass"`, `Object"`, `BasicObject"` (singleton methods)
- `Class` (instance methods)
- `Module` (instance methods)
- `Object` (instance methods) and Kernel
- `BasicObject` (instance methods)

Ruby finds the instance method `Module#constants`

When `Module.constants` is called, Ruby looks at

- `Module"`, `Object"`, `BasicObject"` (singleton methods)
- `Class` (instance methods)
- `Module` (instance methods)
- `Object` (instance methods) and Kernel
- `BasicObject` (instance methods)

this time, Ruby finds the singleton/class method at `Module".constants` as Marc said.

Module defines a singleton method which shadows the instance method. The singleton method returns all known constants whereas the instance method returns the constants defined in current class and its ancestors.