# Ruby: Iterating through Constants

Tags: ruby

I'm just starting to use constants in Ruby.

I have

```
module Constants
  C1 = "foo"
  C2 = "bar"
end
```

I would like to do

```
Constants.each do |c|
  #do something with each one
end
```

but it says

```
undefined method ‘each’ for Constants::module
```

....

Is there a nice way of iterating through a list of constants?

Comment: A useful link for this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309255/how-do-i-get-constants-defined-by-rubys-module-class-via-reflection.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
module Constants
  C1 = "foo"
  C2 = "bar"
end

Constants.constants.each do |c|
  puts "#{c}: #{Constants.const_get(c)}"
end
#=> "C1: foo"
#=> "C2: bar"
```